# I can't pass th:object to controller and mapped to pojo using @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to retrieve object on my controller that mapped to my POJO

My POJO looks like this

```
public interface InventoryDetailPOJO {
    String getItem_cd();
}
```

And this is my form

```
<div class="row d-flex"> 
  <div class="p-3">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-options btn-save">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
<form action="#"
      th:action="@{/stock-list/inventory-detail}"
      method="post"
      th:object="${inventoryDetail}"
      class="pt-3 form-inventory-detail">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="item_cd" class="col-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">
         <span class="pull-right">Item No</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm w-25"
         th:field="*{item_cd}">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And for my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stock-list/inventory-detail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView InventoryDetailSubmitPage(ModelAndView modelAndView,
    @ModelAttribute("inventoryDetail") InventoryDetailPOJO inventoryDetail,
        @RequestParam("item_cd") String item_cd) {

    System.err.println("InventoryDetail: " + inventoryDetail);
    System.err.println("item_cd: " + item_cd);

    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/stock-list");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

There're no item on inventoryDetail when I tried to log it, but There's a value on item_cd

Comment: what does `inventoryDetail.getItem_cd()` return ?

Comment: None. But when I send to my GET method using this pojo. I can retrieve using @query but when I am about to send to my POST method I cant retrieve all fields

Comment: try removing `modelAndView` and `item_cd` from argument list, just keep `inventoryDetail`

Comment: Still the same result. By the way the POJO is not an entity

Comment: Inventorydetail is an interface thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove action="#", like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/stock-list/inventory-detail}"
      method="post"
      th:object="${inventoryDetail}"
      class="pt-3 form-inventory-detail">
```